# Combining multiple Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have these 2 observables:

```
this.areasService.getSelectAreas({})
   .subscribe((result) => this.areasSelect = result.json().data.areas);
this.stationsService.getSelectStations({})
   .subscribe((result) => this.stationsSelect = result.json().data.stations);
```

that fills these 2 variables (async) `this.areasSelect` & `this.stationsSelect`.

I also have a 3rd observable that I need to have these values to continue:

```
this.transportsService.getTransport().subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(this.areasSelect)
     console.log(this.stationsSelect)
})
```

How can I combine these 3 observables?

Comment: You want three of them asynchronously or execute third after first two are run .

Comment: This is a quite good question which is worth to upvote because there are two independent and one dependent observable sequences. @Vivek Doshi's answer is good but I do not recommend you to subscribe to an observable inside of another subscription. There should be a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean that you need the values to continue? You use them as parameters of the getTransport method? If thats the case, I updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `forkJoin`:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

let areaSelect$ = this.areasService.getSelectAreas({})
.map(res => res.json().data.areas)
.do(val => this.areaSelect = val);

let stationSelect$ = this.stationsService.getSelectStations({})
.map(res => res.json().data.stations)
.do(val => this.stationSelect = val);

forkJoin(areaSelect$,stationSelect$)
.mergeMap(data=>{
   //data is an array with 2 positions which contain the results of the 2 requests. data[0] is the vale of this.areaSelect for example
   return this.transportsService.getTransport(data[0],data[1]);
}).subscrite(res => {
  // res is the response value of getTransport
})
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to use `forkJoin` , it will call both of your first async calls and only returns data on both completion , so no need to worry

After that on subscribe you will get result in array of sequence you called the urls or apis.

```
const combined = Observable.forkJoin(
    this.areasService.getSelectAreas({}).map((res) => res.json().data.areas),
    this.stationsService.getSelectStations({}).map((res) => res.json().data.stations)
)

combined.subscribe(latestValues => {

    this.areasSelect = latestValues[0];
    this.stationsSelect = latestValues[1];

    this.transportsService.getTransport().subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(this.areasSelect)
        console.log(this.stationsSelect)
    })
});
```